# Notifications for OpenStreetMap edits in my neighbourhood

Tags: gratis, notification, openstreetmap

I want to get notified when POIs in my neighbourhood get edited in OpenStreetMap, so that I can check if the edits are correct.

As far as I see, https://www.openstreetmap.org/ doesn’t offer such a feature. While the history shows nearby edits, it also lists edits from places far away (not sure why), and it doesn’t seem to offer a specific feed (only a [global one](https://www.openstreetmap.org/history/feed)).

The solution could be a local client or a web app. In case of a client or a self-hosted web app, I need it to be free/libre software for GNU/Linux, but feel free to recommend solutions for other OS, too. In any case, it should be gratis. I don’t care how I get notified (only within the tool, via email, with a feed, …).

Comment: If Android is an option, [StreetComplete](http://apt.qumran.org/fdroid/index/apk/de.westnordost.streetcomplete) sounds very close (link goes to my F-Droid repo). Not tried myself, but might do what you want.

Comment: You might also ask on the OSM forum, or suggest it as a feature (if you can code, you might even implement it and give something to the community). Sounds like a great feature (+1)

Comment: OWL sounds just like what you need: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OWL

Answer (score 2):

Using python, (already installed on most Linux systems), + Requests & BeautifulSoup you can simply poll the OpenStreetMap page - something like:

```
import requests                                                           
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup                                                            
resp = requests.get('https://www.openstreetmap.org/history#map=5/51.509/7.603', 'lxml')  

local_changes = []
of_interest = {  # define the bounding box that you are interested in
  'maxlat': 36.26,
  'maxlon': 2.23,
  'minlat': 36.25,
  'minlon': 2.22
}

def overlaps(a, b):
   """ Function to return whether two areas overlap """
   return not any([
     a['maxlat'] < b['minlat'], # b all above a
     b['maxlat'] < a['minlat'], # a all above b
     a['maxlon'] < b['minlon'], # a all left of b
     b['maxlon'] < a['minlon'] # b all left of a
     ])

if resp.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'html5lib')
    changesets = soup.find('ol', 'changesets')
    changes = changesets.find_all('li')
    for c in changes:
        data = eval(c.attrs['data-changeset'])
        if overlaps(data['bbox'], of_interest):
            local_changes.append(data)

# Add an alert on len(local_changes) > 0:
```

Note that in the above when I tested it an example c would be:

```
<li data-changeset='{"id":46556297,"bbox":{"minlon":2.2336783,"minlat":36.262267,"maxlon":2.2336783,"maxlat":36.262267}}' id="changeset_46556297">  
  <h4>                                                                                                                                              
    <a class="changeset_id" href="/changeset/46556297">                                                                                             
      (no comment)                                                                                                                                  
    </a>                                                                                                                                            
  </h4>                                                                                                                                             
  <div class="comments comments-0">                                                                                                                 
    0                                                                                                                                               
    <span class="icon note grey"></span>                                                                                                            
  </div>                                                                                                                                            
  <div class="details">                                                                                                                             
    Created <abbr title="Fri, 03 Mar 2017 19:08:20 +0000">less than a minute ago</abbr> by <a href="/user/Soheib%20Reguieg">Soheib Reguieg</a>      
    ·                                                                                                                                               
    #46556297                                                                                                                                       
  </div>                                                                                                                                            
</li>
```

So you may wish to save this instead of data which would be:

```
{'bbox': {'maxlat': 36.262267,
  'maxlon': 2.2336783,
  'minlat': 36.262267,
  'minlon': 2.2336783},
 'id': 46556297}
```

You may also wish to get the link from the `soup` for the more button to get and parse more data using `soup.find('a', 'button load_more').attrs['href']` to get the relative location to `get` more entries from.

### On Large Bounding Boxes

The OP expressed concern that there might be entries with huge bounding boxes.
The tests I did when putting the above together showed that *most* edits were of a single feature or a set of features that were reasonably close together but, obviously, an just edit with just 2 widely separated features would have a large bounding box. There are a couple of possible strategies for dealing with this:

1. Don't worry about it if it is infrequent enough.
2. Run a modified version of the above that just counts the number of entries with large bounding boxes for a little while to see how frequent such entries are.
3. Discard any entries with large bounding boxes as probably not being of **local** interest.
4. Invest the time in expanding the above, or using the API, to fetch any large bounding box change sets and analyse for local impact.

### Other requirements

You specified "free/libre software for GNU/Linux" the above is gratis & open source and should work on just about any platform.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if this solution works similar to OSM’s built-in history feature ([example](https://www.openstreetmap.org/history#map=18/52.52200/13.41295)), i.e., it would also have the same drawback of listing edits of POIs that are far away? I guess the issue is that some people include multiple POI edits (that are far away from each other) in one "commit", so there is a huge bounding box (often covering a whole continent).

Comment: @unor The above is using OSM's history feature and then filtering it, which the history feature doesn't do or do _well_.  Adding an edit on bounding boxes.